# Add a button in the recent account area

Tags: button

I would like to place a button in the "Recent Accounts" area in the Account home page:

[image]

The closest I accomplished is to add a button in the List view area, I used an [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000331581&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) in salesforce to place the button, and it looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way I can add a button in the "recent accounts" area?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a custom button in the Recent Account List View is not currently possible. Salesforce is working on this feature. More details [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bqfq).